# Please explain/prove this equality in calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

In one example of my textbook I see that it uses $y\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d(y^2)}{dt}$.  But I am not quite sure where it comes from.  It seems like it is related to integrating $y$ because the existence of $\frac{1}{2}$ and $y^2$ on the right hand side.  Please show me how this equality is true.

Comment: think of chainrule

Comment: by chain rule... look at right hand side and apply chain rule there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac12 \frac{\mathrm d(y^2)} {\mathrm dt} = \frac12 \frac{\mathrm d(y^2)} {\mathrm dy} \frac{\mathrm dy} {\mathrm dt} = \frac12 (2y) \frac{\mathrm dy} {\mathrm dt} = y \frac{\mathrm dy} {\mathrm dt}$$